# validation in angular 5 Validator with space

Tags: angular, validation

i want to show error on when description start with space, space is alow in middle of string  my code is here

```
description: ['', [Validators.required,Validators.pattern(/^\S*$/)]],
```

Comment: Cool. But, do you have a question?

Comment: yes this code prevent to log space in whole string I just want to stop space in start or only space in string

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a regexp specialist, and using a dedicated validator would probably be clearer and more efficient, but this regexp should do the trick:

```
^(\S(.*\S)?)?$
```

Explanation:

- it can contain no character at all (hence the final ?)
- or it should start with a non-white-space (beginning \S)
- followed by

  - nothing (second-to-last ?)
  - or a sequence of any characters terminated by a non-white-space (.*\S)